# Conditionally adding class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<span class=@Model.TotalSent<0?"small":"big">show me only if @Model.TotalSent >0 </span>
```

The above line is a code that I expect class="big" will be rendered if @Model.TotalSent>0
else class="small" will be rendered.

But is not happening
What is the real syntax to  do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span class='@(Model.TotalSent < 0 ? "small" : "big")'>show me only if @Model.TotalSent >0 </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding your expression in parentheses, and make sure you put quotes around your `class`.

```
<span class='@( Model.TotalSent < 0 ? "small" : "big" )'>...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class="@(Model.TotalSent < 0 ? "small":"big")"
```